# list of integer arrays is changed java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am using a list of integer arrays, which is a class variable, to hold the answers. The integer arrays are added to the list in a method, and the results are fine (has 1s). But when I fetch it in main method, the value in it is all 0s! I do not understand, where is the list changed?

```
public class test {
private static int sum=0;
static ArrayList<Integer[]> res = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
private static double max=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 6;
    double B = 23.6;
    double[] menu = { 1.2, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 3.2, 6.2, 7.8, 4.0, 5.6, 10, 6.5 };
    Integer[] solution = new Integer[menu.length];
    combinate(menu, 0, n,0, res, solution);
    for(int i=0;i<res.size();i++) {
        //not getting the element!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //Integer[] sol = res.get(i);
        System.out.println(i+" "+res.get(i));
        System.out.println("Arraylist contains:"+Arrays.toString( res.get( i ) ) );

        double sums = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < res.get(i).length; j++) {
            if(res.get(i)[j]!=null)
                sums += menu[j] * res.get(i)[j];
        }
        if (max < sums && sums < B) {
            max = sums;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max + " max");
}

public static void combinate(double[] left, int n, int k,int sum,
        ArrayList<Integer[]> res, Integer[] holder) {
    if (n == left.length) {
        if (sum == k) {
            res.add(holder);
            System.out.println(res.size()+" "+Arrays.toString(res.get(res.size()-1)));
        }
        sum = 0;
        return;
    }
    {
        holder[n] = 1;
        sum++;
        combinate(left, n + 1, k, sum,res, holder);
        holder[n] = 0;
        sum--;
        combinate(left, n + 1, k, sum,res, holder);
    }
}
```

}
}

The answers looks like this:
when print in method combinate, the list elements looks like [1111100000]

while in main method, there are all [000000000000]

what goes wrong here?

Comment: You don't have an else statement for your if.

Comment: because else is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (sum == k) 
{
    res.add(holder.clone()); // take copy of holder at that moment
    System.out.println(res.size()+" "+Arrays.toString(res.get(res.size()-1)));
}
```

Will Help.

[See Experiment : http://rextester.com/DNNZ68674 ]

Comment: Thank you, why i asked is I gave the answer first (1 minute early) with experiment. Normally we will accept the apt answer came first, and then up vote all answers which really contributed to the question.

Comment: My pleasure. Yes, you are right, you are the first right one. It is fair to give you the vote. :-) I did not know the rules, and thought I can vote multiple times.

Comment: Oh Ok, got it, you are confused with vote and accept :) , Accept is the tick mark we grand to the accepted answer and Up/Down votes are what we do with the triangles (Up to good answer and down to bad). Hope it help through out your stay in SO.

Comment: Thanks Biju, now I get the whole rule. I am voting the triangles for other answers, but I don't have enough reputations yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have your method "combinate" return new res like `public static ArrayList<Integer[]> combinate(double[] left, int n, int k,int sum,
        ArrayList<Integer[]> res, Integer[] holder)`

then in your main : `res = combinate(...)`;

Comment: Yes, you are right! But even after I delete the res in combinate method, main still prints wrong res.

Comment: On looking at your code, it seems your condition if ( n == left.length() ) never goes in because n = 0  and left.length is 11 ( menu's length is 11 )

Comment: It is recursive, so the condition is fine. You may try it in your IDE, but there is a "}" missed at the end in my code, I do not know how to add it in the right format.

Comment: Ok. didn't see that. You don't need the { } in the last block { holder[n] = 1; ... }

Comment: Thanks so much Svasa and Luke for your kind help! The combinate method is getting the combinations of the menu.  I am using recursive way to do this. The combination comes out fine. Just the results does not get to the main method.

Answer (score 1):

You have only a single Integer[] instance that you add to your result (`res.add(holder)`) and overwrite while unwinding the recursion.

You should add a clone of your array to the result:

> res.add(holder.clone());

Answer (score 1):

In the original code you're passing the "holder"-variable as a parameter. In Java parameters are passed **by value**.
This means, you can change the value inside of the combinate-function, but this will never be reflected back to the calling main-function - that's the nature of call by value.

Comment: Nice comment! I learn Java's pass by value in a hard way. Thanks so much!